# Use Taxonomy Checkbox to add Custom Post Type to Main WordPress Loop & Feed

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem with WordPress Custom Post Types that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

I would like to have a category or a custom taxonomy checkbox on my custom post type, and if this one is checked, then display the post in the WordPress main loop and in the WordPress feed.

Note: I don't want to display all posts from my custom post type in the main loop and feed, only the ones that are checked.

Is this even possible to achieve? I've tried to google for a solution, but with no luck so far.

Thanks!

// Jens.

Comment: You want the check on the post or on the category of the custom post type? Also, after you make the check system, you want the selected posts to show side by side with the regular ones in the main loop, right?

Comment: @nunorbatista Yes, I want to show them side by side ordered by date, mixed normal posts and my custom post type. I want to do the check on the custom post type.

Comment: To start you need to add custom fields to the post by adding a plugin like advanced custom post types. This way you'll have your checkboxes. About showing the posts, I'll try to write an answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @nunorbatista , I have everything in place, the only thing that remains is the function to modify the loop and feed. Do you have any ideas on this perhaps?